# Creating a int that never gets reset

Tags: xcode4

im kinda new to programing with Xcode. how would i make a variable suck as a int which holds a a score. Which i want to be kept even if the phone is shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NSUserDefaults** for this, which means you can have your value back even if the phone is shutdown:

Use this method to save your Integer

```
- (void)setInteger:(NSInteger)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

And right after use

```
- (BOOL)synchronize
```

So that the data is saved.

So basically save this value before your application exits and then when your application is loading again, you can get your value back with this method:

```
- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

You will have to use NSInteger to save, since you cannot save primitive values with NSUserDefaults.

Reference: [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Im sorry but I'm confused for a method don't you need the  { } things? if so what would i put in the { }

Comment: @Kevin hall that is yhe method signature, you do not nees to create any methods, just use the existing methods in my answer.